# Power series solution to a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following partial differential equation:

$u_t = u_xu_y$

I know that the solution can be formed via power series. I want to find a solution of degree $2$ that satisfies an initial condition $u(0,x,y) = x+y-2x^2$.

I understand the strategy of the solution would be to take partial derivative combinations of $u$ up to the second degree. So these would involve

$u_t,u_x,u_y,u_{tt},u_{xx},u_{yy},u_{tx},u_{ty},u_{xy},u_{xt},u_{yx},u_{yt}$

For a grand total of 12 terms in the series. Then, the function would need to be evaluated at (0,0,0)...(0,0,1)...(0,1,0)..etc to get the coefficients.

After that, I can construct coefficients of partial derivative combinations to form a series and plug in my IVP condition.

However...$what$ am I differentiating exactly? Where is $u$? Do I just rearrange the terms $u_t$, $u_x$, and $u_y$ to get what I need?

Comment: Try to make a polynomial where the monomials are the same as the indexes of the partial derivatives you listed

Answer (score 1):

Assume a solution of the form
$$
u(t, x, y) = c_{000} + c_{100}t + c_{010}x + c_{001}y + c_{200}t^{2} + c_{020}x^{2} + c_{002}y^{2} + c_{110}tx + c_{011}xy + c_{101}ty
$$
Since $u(0, x, y) = x + y - 2x^{2}$, we find that
$$
u(t, x, y) = c_{100}t + x + y + c_{200}t^{2} - 2x^{2} + c_{110}tx + c_{101}ty
$$
Write out partial derivatives:
\begin{align}
\partial_{t}u &= c_{100} + 2c_{200}t + c_{110}x + c_{101}y \\
\partial_{x}u &= 1 - 4x + c_{110}t \\
\partial_{y}u &= 1 + c_{101}t
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
c_{100} + 2c_{200}t + c_{110}x + c_{101}y 
&=
1 + (c_{101}+c_{110})t -4x -4c_{101}xt + c_{110}c_{101}t^{2}
\end{align}
and as such $c_{101} = 0$ and $c_{100} = 1$, $c_{110} = -4$, and $c_{200} = -2$.
\begin{align}
\boxed{u(t, x, y) = t + x + y -2t^2 -2x^2 -4tx}
\end{align}
I don't know why you need all those other terms.